# MySQL : Stored Procedure from Trigger giving duplicate results

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

I have created a stored procedure to insert data into an audit table. The procedure accepts an argument that takes table name and same value is inserted into the audit table along with PK.

When i'm calling this stored procedure from AFTER DELETE trigger, from multiple tables it is inserting duplicate values. Basically, same PK value is getting inserted for all table names in the audit table. So, if i delete a record from a table, number of inserts in audit table for single delete = number of triggers.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ins_log(
trigger_name VARCHAR(64),
column_name VARCHAR(64),
column_value VARCHAR(255),
requested_by VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO log (request_id,reference_schema, reference_table, reference_field, reference_id, action_performed, requested_by)
SELECT 
(SELECT trx_id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX WHERE trx_mysql_thread_id = CONNECTION_ID()),
EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, 
EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, 
column_name,
column_value, 
CONCAT(ACTION_TIMING,'_',EVENT_MANIPULATION),
IFNULL(requested_by,CURRENT_USER()) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = trigger_name AND TRIGGER_SCHEMA = SCHEMA();
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_table_ad
AFTER DELETE
ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
CALL sp_ins_log('table_name',old.id);
```

**But, if i put the same insert query individually in each trigger, it works fine.**

Reproduced the issue [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s3nSEgHcPCgS9ofzNXpqkq/0)

Compare this with direct execution of INSERT query inside SP.

Comment: @Akina I have updated but unable to reproduce in this environment. I'm running on MySQL version 5.7.27. Not sure is it because of FK relation between tables. But there is no cascade delete even with FK.

Comment: Found something on MySQL docs.


`Replication Considerations

Use of stored routines can cause replication problems. This issue is discussed further in [Section 24.7, “Stored Program Binary Logging”][1]

The --replicate-wild-do-table=db_name.tbl_name option applies to tables, views, and triggers. It does not apply to stored procedures and functions, or events. To filter statements operating on the latter objects, use one or more of the --replicate-*-db options.

[1]:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html`

Comment: Nothing to do with constraints. Still happening after removing FK

Comment: I have narrowed it down. It seems like issue is occuring when SELECTING from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS inside store procedure.

Comment: please add full stored procedure code

Comment: @Nikita code updated. If we call this SP it inserts as many rows as triggers in the schema.
But if we execute the select without SP, it returns only single result

Comment: @Akina I was able to reproduce the issue. Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple - inaccuracy. Variable name and column name interference. You type `WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = trigger_name`. Both `TRIGGER_NAME` and `trigger_name` are treated as input variable name, and this condition is always true. You have 2 triggers matched the rest condition `TRIGGER_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()`, so query returns 2 rows.

Simply rename input variables. Or add table alias and allow the server to distinguish the column name and variable name: `WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS.TRIGGER_NAME = trigger_name AND TRIGGER_SCHEMA = SCHEMA();`.

Comment: What a blunder on my end.  
Thanks for pointing out name collision.